# ImageMagick distortion of the mask for the distortion of the face

Tags: imagemagick, distortion

Good afternoon
Can using a library imagemagick apply to image distortion on the mask?

By analogy with this example  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#spherical

I wanted to create the effect of a "fat face" with the help of such distortion. The problem is that this must be individually increase cheeks and chin. I can not understand how to look like a mask distortion in this case.

Comment: did you get the Way ??? If Yes then please help me

Comment: No, now I just put the experiments. The general feeling that this is what you need. True one distortion does not get a good result. If you look the Fatbooth. When applying Effet on a white sheet shows that the chin is applied individual mask.

Comment: They actually, applying Distortion separately and then blending with original one.I am also trying for that but in Shepard Distortion i am not getting an Image due to some Coding.So if you find something then please Share it with me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898139/ios-imagemagick-how-to-code-to-apply-shepardsdistortion-on-image/20903964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also wandering for same thing, but i am not able to implement this in iOS. Here i can share my Logic.
Go for "ShepardsDistortion" in ImageMagick. This allows you to distort image pixel by pixel, for that you have to first apply Face Detection algorithm.

https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#freeform_distorts