# ios - ImageMagick How to code to apply ShepardsDistortion on image

Tags: ios, image-processing, imagemagick, distortion

I am new to ImageMagick,and i want to develop an effect of ShepardsDistortion on source image. i gone through many posts and sites, but i didn't find way to implement "ShepardsDistortion" in iOS.

```
    MagickWand *mw = NewMagickWand();
    MagickSetFormat(mw, "png");

    UIImage *sourceImage=[_sourceImgView image];
    NSData *imgData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(sourceImage);
    MagickReadImageBlob(mw, [imgData bytes], [imgData length]);
    Image *image=GetImageFromMagickWand(mw);

    DistortImage(image, ShepardsDistortion, , ,);
```

I done upto this, but i dont know what to pass as arg in DitortImage(). So if anyone knows then help me.

**EDIT:**

```
-(void)distortImage{

    MagickWandGenesis();
    MagickWand * wand;
    MagickBooleanType status;

    wand = NewMagickWand();
    MagickSetFormat(wand, "png");
    status = MagickReadImage(wand,"chess.png");

    // Arguments for Shepards
    double points[8];
    points[0] = 250; // First X point (starting)
    points[1] = 250; // First Y point (starting)
    points[2] =  50; // First X point (ending)
    points[3] = 150; // First Y point (ending)
    points[4] = 500; // Second X point (starting)
    points[5] = 380; // Second Y point (starting)
    points[6] = 600; // Second X point (ending)
    points[7] = 460; // Second Y point (ending)


    MagickDistortImage(wand,ShepardsDistortion,8,points,MagickFalse);
    NSString * tempFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out.png"];
    MagickWriteImage(wand,[tempFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    UIImage * imgObj = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath];
    _resultImgView.image=imgObj;

//    
//    unsigned char * cBlob;
//    size_t data_size;
//    cBlob = MagickGetImageBlob(wand, &data_size);
//    NSData * nsBlob = [NSData dataWithBytes:cBlob length:data_size];
//    UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithData:nsBlob];
//    _resultImgView.image=uiImage;

    MagickWriteImage(wand,"out.png");
    wand=DestroyMagickWand(wand);
    MagickWandTerminus();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments are passed to DistortImage as the start of a list of doubles, and size information about the list. Example:

```c
size_t SizeOfPoints = 8;
double Points[SizeOfPoints];
DistortImage(image,
             ShepardsDistoration,
             SizeOfPoints,
             Points,
             MagickFalse,
             NULL
            );
```

In your example, you seem to be mixing [MagickWand](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) & [MagickCore](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php) methods; which, seems unnecessary and confusing. I would keep this distortion simple, and only use MagickWand's [MagickDistortImage](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickDistortImage) method. Here's a example in [c](/questions/tagged/c)

```c
int main(int argc. const char **argv)
{
  MagickWandGenesis();
  MagickWand * wand;
  MagickBooleanType status;

  wand = NewMagickWand();
  status = MagickReadImage(wand,"logo:");

  // Arguments for Shepards
  double points[8];
  // 250x250 -> 50x150
  points[0] = 250; // First X point (starting)
  points[1] = 250; // First Y point (starting)
  points[2] =  50; // First X point (ending)
  points[3] = 150; // First Y point (ending)
  // 500x380 -> 600x460
  points[4] = 500; // Second X point (starting)
  points[5] = 380; // Second Y point (starting)
  points[6] = 600; // Second X point (ending)
  points[7] = 460; // Second Y point (ending)

  MagickDistortImage(wand,ShepardsDistortion,8,points,MagickFalse);
  MagickWriteImage(wand,"out.png");

  wand=DestroyMagickWand(wand);
  MagickWandTerminus();

  return 0;
}
```

Resulting in a distorted translated image ([details](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards))

[image: ShepardsDistortion Example]

#### Edit

For iOS, you can use `NSTemporaryDirectory` (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267432/using-the-c-api-for-imagemagick-on-iphone-to-convert-to-monochrome/18282136#18282136)), or create an image dynamically using NSData (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956355/imagemagick-in-iphone-how-to-convert-image-object-to-uiimage-in-iphone)).

Example with temporary path:

```objc
NSString * tempFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() 
                             stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out.png"];
MagickWriteImage(self.wand,
    [tempFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
UIImage * imgObj = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath];
```

And an example with NSData + blob

```objc
unsigned char * cBlob;
size_t data_size;
cBlob = MagickGetImageBlob(wand, &data_size);
NSData * nsBlob = [NSData dataWithBytes:cBlob length:data_size];
UIImage * uiImage = [UIImage imageWithData:nsBlob];
```

Comment: Thanks Alot! +100 for You Bro! Can You give any resource for all such methods for iOS ??

Comment: I tried This but i am not able to get output file! Which method should i use to get output to either in UIImage or in a File at specify Path?? I used  MagickWriteImageFile(wand, fptr) to write file but output file contins Zero bytes

Comment: Thanks for Your Edit, but Brother ImageObject is remaining nil in 1st case and in second one it is Firing exception, I am Using code provided in Edit

Comment: I checked Temporary Directory also, But No File is Generated in that, thats why i am getting NIL as UIImage Object. So What Should i do?

Comment: Please Help me Emcconville

Comment: @Mrug, I can't help you. The issues you're experiencing are vary localized to your project. If you need more help, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) & [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/). This site is not structured to handle [XY Problems](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY%20Problem) or [Help Vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: Thanks EmcconVille !! I know it might me confusing. but My simple Query is, Object which should be created after MagickWriteImage(), is not actually Generated after that. It remainls NULL

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
MagickWandGenesis();
magick_wand = NewMagickWand();
double points[24];
points[0] = 250; 
points[1] = 250; 
points[2] =  50; 
points[3] = 150; 
points[4] = 0; 
points[5] = 0; 
points[6] =  0; 
points[7] = 0; 
points[8] = self.frame.width; 
points[9] = 0; 
points[10] = self.frame.width; 
points[11] = 0; 
points[12] = self.frame.width; 
points[13] = self.frame.height; 
points[14] = self.frame.width; 
points[15] = self.frame.height; 
points[16] = self.frame.width; 
points[17] = self.frame.height; 
points[18] = self.frame.width; 
points[19] = self.frame.height;
points[20] = 0; 
points[21] = self.frame.height; 
points[22] = 0; 
points[23] = self.frame.height;  
NSData * dataObject = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Imagemagick-logo.png"]);//UIImageJPEGRepresentation([imageViewButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal], 90);
MagickBooleanType status;
status = MagickReadImageBlob(magick_wand, [dataObject bytes], [dataObject length]);
if (status == MagickFalse) {
    ThrowWandException(magick_wand);
}

// posterize the image, this filter uses a configuration file, that means that everything in IM should be working great
status =  MagickDistortImage(magick_wand,ShepardsDistortion,24,points,MagickFalse);

//status = MagickOrderedPosterizeImage(magick_wand, "h8x8o");
if (status == MagickFalse) {
    ThrowWandException(magick_wand);
}

size_t my_size;
unsigned char * my_image = MagickGetImageBlob(magick_wand, &my_size);
NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:my_image length:my_size];
free(my_image);
magick_wand = DestroyMagickWand(magick_wand);
MagickWandTerminus();
UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
[data release];

[imageViewButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[image release];
```